# Solving an equation that has that has an equal sign involving mods, not a sign for congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

My Discrete Mathematics Teacher gave me the following question on a test:

> Find the Smallest non-negative integer $x$ that satisfies the
>   equation: $$3(x+7) = [4(9-x) + 1] \mod 5$$

When I first looked at this question, I first noticed that there was an equals sign, but not a congruence sign.

My understanding was then that the equation was taken mod $5$. After using trial and error, I found that $x=3$ yielded:

$$3(3+7)  = [4(9-3) + 1] \mod 5$$
$$30  = 25 \mod 5$$

When both sides are taken mod $5$, both sides would yield $0$.

However, my teacher, when giving us back the tests, told me (in regards to this question because I got it wrong) that:

$$30 \equiv 25 \mod 5$$

And also that the $\mod 5$ written in the question was for the right-hand side, not the left-hand side.

To this I replied to him saying that it doesn't matter if only one side was taken $\mod 5$. You can take both sides $\mod 5$ again to get:

$$30 \mod 5 = (25 \mod 5) \mod 5$$

Which would still equate to $0$ on both sides.

What you do guys think? Is my process correct?

Comment: If you use "mod", it is always $\equiv$ and not $=$.

Comment: @Dietrich: That’s true only when you use the *relation* mod. When you use the *binary operation* mod you can certainly have $=$. The teacher is evidently using that latter.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so when you are using a mod with $=$, would my answer still be correct?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know and that's why I was confused when my teacher used an equals sign. Equations involving mod are usually written as congruences

Comment: I see. I only know $x\equiv y \bmod m$, from elementary number theory. In other words, I usually see this in exercises as $3(x+7)\equiv 4(9-x)+1 \bmod 5$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I understand the relation mod in this problem. However, when you put an $=$ sign into the equation, are you able to then take both sides mod $5$?

Comment: @Varun: On further examination I have to retract the last sentence of my comment to Dietrich: if the teacher were using the binary operation, the problem would have no solution, so the relation must be intended after all. And on that basis I agree that $x=3$ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is `mod 5`only for the right-hand side, it means we have the mod 5  `function`, i. e. the remainder when we divide by $5$, and not the `congruence relation`, i. e. ‘having the same remainder’.

With the first interpretation, there is $\color{red}{\text{no solution}}$, because if $x\ge 0$, $3(x+7)\ge 21$, while anything mod $5$ lies in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

With the second interpretation, the congruence equation can be rewritten as 
$$7x\equiv 16\mod 5\iff2x\equiv 1\mod  3,$$
and the solution is the inverse of $2$ modulo $5$, i. e. $\;\color{red}{x\equiv 3\mod 5}$.

*Final remark:*
There should be a difference in the notation of the  interpretations: the *function* is denoted $x\bmod5$, while the congruence relation is denoted $x\equiv y\mod 5$ (observe the difference in spacing). If one wants to avoid any ambiguity, one may note the relation: $x\equiv y\pmod 5$.

Comment: Can you take $\mod 5$ on both sides of an equation?

Comment: As a function? It amounts to write the congruence modulo $5$.